# jquery code works in chrome but not firefox or safari

Tags: jquery, firefox, safari

Hi i am trying to run a function if the left mouse is pressed and dragged.

i can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the following code:

```
var leftbuttondown = false;
$("#tiles p").live("mousedown mouseover", function (e) {
(e.which === 1) ? leftbuttondown = true : leftbuttondown = false ;
if(leftbuttondown === true){
updateMap(this);
}
});
```

the code works as expected in chrome but in firefox and safari it is executing the code on mouseover regardless of anything being pressed.

i have also tried the following

```
$("#tiles p").live("mousedown mouseover", function (e) {
if(e.which === 1){
updateMap(this);
}
});
```

again works as expected in chrome but not in firefox or safari...

i have checked here:

http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

which tells me that the left mouse button for each browser is = 1

its begining to frustrate me so any and all help will be awesome

Comment: why can't you just split it into two event bindings? Also, use `delegate` or `on` instead of `live`.

Comment: live is used because the elements it applies to are generated on the fly, separating the bindings would require a third binding of mouseup I was trying to do it in as few lines as possible and with it working as you'd expect in chrome i just wondered why it wasn't working in safari or firefox. Separating the bindings does work by the way in all browsers although can be a little bit buggy at times

Comment: Did you check the value of event.which? Insert `console.log(event.which)` and post the result here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that firefox set the e.which to 1 even if the button is not pressed.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2c5kz/)